# How to link two columns based on a third columns to build network

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am new in networkx and python.
I have a database has 3 columns like this:

| f_id | s_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 506678 | 24-05-2005 |

i want to create a network by networkx but first i need to connect the nodes based on the date

for example:
lf_id -> s_id

where (->) the link is the date

I know how to create the network as a directed network but i have tried to connect the two columns and i couldn't do that so what i did is something like this:

```
import netowkrx as nx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("connect_data.csv")

df1 = df[['f_id', 's_id', 'date']]

G = nx.DiGraph()
G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df,['f_id','s_id'])
```

but that not make it right! and i couldn't figure out a way can anyone help please on how to connect the two columns based on the dates.

Comment: `nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='f_id', target='s_id')`.

Comment: Thank you Quang for your responds but in this way will not connect the two columns by the date!! the link should be the date columns and the nodes should be the f_id and s_id

Comment: what do you mean by *the link is date*? you can add property to the edge with `edge_attr='date'`?

Comment: i meant that the edge between the f_id and the s_id should be the date.. the connection between them it should be the date. I hope i explain it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nx.from_pandas_edgelist`, which allows to create a graph from a dataframe with the edge data. Since it appears that you want the `date` to be picked up by the graph, you can also add *edge attributes*. The resulting edges would look as follows:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='f_id', target='s_id', edge_attr='date')

G.edges(data=True)
# EdgeDataView([(12345, 506678, {'date': '24-05-2005'})])
```

Comment: Thank you so much yatu